# Do Mass versions of spells count as the base spell for magic item creation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

Certain magic items require that the crafter know certain spells. From the [rules on magic item creation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/)

> These prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item’s creator (although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed).

Some spells also have a "mass" version of the spell that usually functions in a similar way as the normal spell but affecting more targets. I am wondering if these mass versions of the spell also count for the purposes of creating a magic item.

For example, if a character knows [Feather Step, Mass](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=feather%20step) (but not Feather Step), does this qualify for creating [Feather Step Slippers](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Feather%20Step%20Slippers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

The mass version of a spell is a different spell than the base version. Similarly the greater, lesser, and I-IX versions are also different spells, though they may be based around the same one. Each of these versions of a spell alters how that spell works, in this case it allows the spell to affect multiple creatures.

A bard who has Mass Feather Step as a spell known, but not Feather Step, cannot cast Feather Step. Similarly, Mass Feather Step not count as Feather Step for the purposes of creating magic items, feats, or other abilities that may require Feather Step.

Comment: Definitely the RAW answer, though I'd note that it'd seem fair for a GM to allow a higher-level version of a spell to count as the lesser for these prerequisites - there aren't really any hideous balance concerns.